# Regular expression shouldn't contains whole word and dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to write the regular expression that shouldn't contains word [apple]
and also shouldn't contains dots [.]

*Some apple - false*

*Some other string - true*

*Some other string . - false*

I was thinking about `^((?!apple).)*$`, that excludes whole word

Comment: Please edit your title to something that actually describes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
s.matches("(?s)(?!.*apple)[^.]*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zSVTk2/1) (the pattern is adjusted for a single multiline string, do not use that pattern in the demo).

The regex is `(?s)^(?!.*apple)[^.]*$` that means:

- `(?s)` - a `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier that makes `.` match any char including a newline
- `^` - start of string (implicit in `.matches()`)
- `(?!.*apple)` - a negative lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location (at the string start), matches any chars, as many as possible, followed with a `apple` substring (if the pattern is not found, there is no match)
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than a dot
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `.matches()`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the dot as a character to exclude. Since the `.` is a control character in regex, it must be escaped:

```
^((?!apple|\.).)*$
```

In this case, we are telling it to match 0 or more of any character as long as there is no pattern matching 'apple' or '.' anywhere in the string.

This expression can be deconstructed as follows:

```
^     = Start of string
(     = Start of capture group
(     = Start of capture group
?!    = Negative Look ahead
apple = First thing to look for
|     = Logical Or
\.    = Match a literal . character
)     = End of capture group
.     = Match any character
)     = End of capture group
*     = Match zero or more
$     = End of String
```